# Need help getting pandas to recognize my timeseries dataframe is in 15min intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this dataset:

```
Data                 A
2015-01-01 00:15:00  0
2015-01-01 00:30:00  1
2015-01-01 00:45:00  2
2015-01-01 01:00:00  3
2015-01-01 01:15:00  4
```

I'm trying to set the data to a frequency. I've got pandas to recognize the DateTime to the index.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:15:00',
           '2015-01-01 00:30:00', '2015-01-01 00:45:00',
           '2015-01-01 01:00:00', '2015-01-01 01:15:00',
           '2015-01-01 01:30:00', '2015-01-01 01:45:00',
           '2015-01-01 02:00:00', '2015-01-01 02:15:00',
           ...
           '2016-09-30 21:30:00', '2016-09-30 21:45:00',
           '2016-09-30 22:00:00', '2016-09-30 22:15:00',
           '2016-09-30 22:30:00', '2016-09-30 22:45:00',
           '2016-09-30 23:00:00', '2016-09-30 23:15:00',
           '2016-09-30 23:30:00', '2016-09-30 23:45:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Data', length=61340, freq=None)
```

I've tried doing this

```
   df.asfreq(freq='15M')
```

But I get the following error

```
 ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: kindly provide the source dataframe as a dictionary : ``df.to_dict('records')``. Also, the error message, is it for the sample dataframe, or your actual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with some aggregation function like `sum`, `mean`, `first`:

```
df.resample('15M').sum()
```

Comment: I get the error  '' TypeError: resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'freq' ''

Comment: @Sam can you test now?

Comment: yes, I can test

Comment: use resample and ffill to handle any resulting nans

Comment: @GoldenLion  I used df.resample('15M').mean().ffill() but 15M is interpreted as 15 months and not 15 minutes

Comment: use seconds instead of minutes if necessary

Comment: @GoldenLion  I put '900S' instead of 15 minutes and it works. Now it recognizes the frequency of 900 seconds. Thank you

Comment: @GoldenLion sorry I don't have 15 reputation, so I can't do that